# Subseting column in one data frame using two columns in another data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have tried for the similar problem on SO but couldn't.

I have two data frames. I want to subset one column in one data frame using two columns in another data frame.

The data frame are as following.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(22,23,22,34,21),
                  y = c(1,4,2,3,2))
df1
   x y
1 22 1
2 23 4
3 22 2
4 34 3
5 21 2

df2 <- data.frame(a = c("John", "Matt", "foo","boo"),
                  b = c(4, NA, NA,2), 
                  c = c(3, NA, 3, 3))


df2

     a  b  c
1 John  4  3
2 Matt NA NA
3  foo NA  3
4  boo  2  3
```

I want to subset column *df1$y* using column b and c from dataframe *df2* using vectorized operation.
The output should in list form as following

```
df1

df1[1]
   x y
2 23 4
4 34 3

df1[2]


df1[3]
   x y
4 34 3


df1[4]
   x y
3 22 2
4 34 3
5 21 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
dfnew<-list()
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  dfnew[[i]]<-df1[which(df1$y %in% df2[i,2:3]),]
}
```

Result:

```
dfnew
[[1]]
   x y
2 23 4
4 34 3

[[2]]
[1] x y
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[3]]
   x y
4 34 3

[[4]]
   x y
3 22 2
4 34 3
5 21 2
```

Comment: Thanks! but can I get the similar result using vectorized operation.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply`

```
lapply(split(df2[-1], as.character(df2$a)), function(x) df1[df1$y %in% unlist(x),])
```